# Service httpd restart isn't displaying any info

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

After updating Apache it's no longer printing info on restart:

```
Stopping httpd: [ OK ] 
Starting httpd: [ OK ]
```

When entering:

```
service httpd restart
```

It is completely silent.

When I stop apache I see the following message:

```
Found 1 leftover httpd processes. Killing.
```

I'm running Apache/2.4.34 (Unix) on CentOS 6.10. I have updated Apache using Custombuild (DirectAdmin)

**Question:** Is the leftover httpd process preventing Apache from printing info on restart? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The showing of messages on service restart is part of the `sysvinit` scripts. That code in particular is shared among all scripts.

The gist is that the update must have overwritten `/etc/init.d/httpd`. You can copy an existing script (or recover the `httpd` one from the distribution's rpm) and fix executable paths or other services that should be running (such as htcacheclean, if it exists in your apache build) based on the one installed by the update.

Now, be aware that `systemd` is also completely silent when restarting services, although (newer) CentOS [init scripts](https://github.com/fedora-sysv/initscripts/blob/master/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions#L31) do wrap the call to show messages, if invoked that way.

Also, the rogue left-over process is something you should look at but no, it's not the cause of the messages not printing anymore.